# Why Can my Phone Calculator do $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}$ but not $\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, calculator, euler-mascheroni-constant

When I type in the identity $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}$ on my phone calculator (LG phone running Android), I get the correct result of $-1$

However, when I simply type $\sqrt{-1}$, it returns an error.

Why can the calculator do $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}$, but not do $\sqrt{-1}$ if $\sqrt{-1}$ is a direct part of $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}$?

Comment: Maybe it's hard-coded?

Comment: Maybe $e^{\phi\sqrt{-1}}$ is hardcoded as $\operatorname{cis}\phi$

Comment: Maybe it can't display complex numbers? $\sqrt{-1}$ is complex but $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}$ isn't. (I really doubt this though - it'd be impressive for a calculator to determine that $e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}})$ really has a $0$ imaginary part and not just a $10^{-99}$ imaginary part or something)

Comment: Can it "do" $e^{0.5\pi\sqrt{-1}}$?

Comment: @MPW No, returns error.

Comment: Then that give credence to the suggestion that it can't display complex results, only real results. Do you have a manual for the calculator?

Comment: @MPW No I do not. I don't believe phone calculators come with manuals. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Now I'm suspicious. How do you "type" $\sqrt{-1}$? What is the exact sequence of keystrokes?

Comment: (Well, I guess I meant a manual for the app, if that's what it is)

Comment: @mpw [ √ ], [ - ], [ 1 ], [ ) ]

Comment: Not [1], [+/-], $[\sqrt{}]$ ? Hmm...

Comment: Can it "do" $\sqrt{-1} \times e^{0.5\pi\sqrt{-1}}$?

Comment: @Nex Yes, returns -1.

Comment: just adding that this seems lg-specific... my Samsung galaxy s5 running android returns both expressions as the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^{\pi\sqrt{-1}}=\cos \pi + \sqrt{-1}\sin \pi=-1+0=-1$ which is a real number

BUT

$\sqrt{-1}=i$ is a complex number with a zero real part and a non-zero imaginary part.

Computation of complex numbers is possible in any calculator but showing the results containing imaginary numbers is not possible except in certain high-grade calculators.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks. Typo corrected. :-)

Comment: Interesting. So you are saying it *can* do complex calculations, but not display them? That seems like a waste. How hard could it be to display complex values?

Comment: @JamieSanborn I have a CASIO fx-3650 SUPER-FX calculator which can show complex numbers and make different calculations like argument,modulus, etc. But it still cannot display the entire complex number in one screen at a time. It first displays the real part and then you need to toggle the screen to see the imaginary part with a small "i" visible in the right corner.

Comment: What do you mean by "Computation of complex numbers is possible in any calculator"?

Comment: @Nex It can calculate $\sqrt{-1}$ but then the calculator realises it is an imaginary number and hence fails to display the result due to absence of proper hardware and settings.

Comment: Some calculators don't have square roots (they have only addition, subtraction, multiplication and division)....

Comment: @Nex  I have never seen or heard of one such calculator .. perhaps they exist but then it is not applicable to them.